# Cannot step into the code while debugging a C DLL file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I have a separate Visual Studio *solution* with the DLL written in C. I use it in another solution; in a console C++ project. While debugging the console project I step into a DLL function.

However, the page is opened reporting that `There is no source code available for the current location` with call stack location `MyConsole.exe!_tailMerge_MyLibrary_dll()`. I use delay loading of the DLL file in the console project. As the no source code page is displayed, I inspect the output window and find symbols loaded of the DLL line. Why does Visual Studio 2012 fail to step into this DLL code?

Comment: Is your dll is built with debug information ?

Comment: Generate Debug Info: Yes (/DEBUG)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it sounds like VS is able to load the dll, but it doesn't know where (on your machine) to find the source files. The dll contains the binary it needs to link and compile, but it doesn't have the physical source files with it. I would suspect you need to import the files that make up the dll into your project and point it to the files in order for the debugger to be able to let you "step" through them.

Comment: I added dll project to test console solution without any result. the source code is still not found

Comment: @AlvinWong then it needs to add dll project to solution where c++ console is and add a project reference to the console project?

Comment: @AlvinWong I added dll project to test console solution and added reference to dll project in test console project. still can not locate the sources

Comment: I wonder if there are any bugs in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the following solved mine. I set "Debugger Type" to "Mixed" on the properties page of the main project. My main project is managed code while the .dll is native.

Answer (score 0):

It happens, when dealing with external projects that Visual Studio asks you if you have the code.  If you cancel the process, the requested file gets added to a list in the solution and it remembers NOT to ask for the file again.

Check your `Solution Property Pages > Debug Source Files`. First, make sure your file is NOT in **Do not look for these source files:** and then make sure you add the location of the sources in the **Directories containing source code**. This should help fix the problem.

Comment: I added the folder with dll sources without effect

Comment: there are no problems with c# console project

Comment: Did you generate the PDB for your DLL?

Comment: by all means, that would not have worked in c# test console project then

Comment: and browse to its sources with step into? that is not possible. be sure there is pdb generated in debug build

Comment: Isn't that what you're NOT able to do, to browse the sources? I'm not sure I understand your issue...

Comment: yes, I can not browse to sources of the c dll project from c++ console project. I can browse to sources from c# console however using the same step into while debugging